# Como exibir a soma de um valor X aonde estiver com um mesmo nome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, vamos supor que tenho um objeto que tenha os seguintes valores

```
    var json = [
    {"nome":"Coisa A", qtd:2},
    {"nome":"Coisa A", qtd:3},
    {"nome":"Coisa B", qtd:5},
    {"nome":"Coisa B", qtd:7}
    ]
```

Bom, eu consigo retornar esses valores para exibir em uma lista com o angular, eu queria exibir no html assim, somando as "qtd" e mantendo apenas um nome do mesmo jeito abaixo.

```
    Coisa A possui 5
    Coisa B possui 12
```

Comment: Você tem controle sobre a geração desse json? O ideal é que ele já venha pronto para exibir, embora não seja difícil fazer em js.

Comment: Tenho sim, mais estou usando o mesmo bind para dois locais da página então não posso já trazer com esse filtro. tenho que aplicar somente na hora de exibir em uma lista no html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a função nativa `reduce()` para realizar soma por agrupamento. Exemplo abaixo:

```js
var json = [
  {"nome":"Coisa A", qtd:2},
  {"nome":"Coisa A", qtd:3},
  {"nome":"Coisa B", qtd:5},
  {"nome":"Coisa B", qtd:7}
];

var result = json.reduce(function(res, obj) {

  if (res._array.indexOf(obj.nome) === -1) {  
    res._array.push(obj.nome);
    res[obj.nome] = obj.qtd;
  }
  else {
    res[obj.nome] += obj.qtd;
  }

  return res;

}, {_array:[]});

console.log(result);
```

Seu resultado será:

```
{
  "_array": [
    "Coisa A",
    "Coisa B"
  ],
  "Coisa A": 5,
  "Coisa B": 12
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem o que deseja, mas para fazer uma lista simples vindo de um `JSON`, basta fazer o `ng-repeat` com o `JSON`.

Um exemplo seria:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="var in items">{{var.nome}} possui {{var.qtd}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

E no Angular, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        nome: "Coisa A",
        qtd: "2"
    }, {
         nome: "Coisa B",
         qtd: "3"
    }, {
         nome: "Coisa C",
         qtd: "7"
    }];
}
```

O resultado será:

```
Coisa A possui 2
Coisa B possui 3
Coisa C possui 7
```

Veja um exemplo funcional [no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/962/)

Comment: Quase cara meu problema não é exibir dessa forma, mais é o seguinte veja que tenho duas "COISAS A" e duas "COISAS B", e cada uma delas tem um quantidade diferente eu quero somar as quantidades e manter apenas um nome.